# flush iptables with 'iptables-apply' on ubuntu

Tags: iptables

The following entries are used to flush the iptable rules:

/sbin/iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -F

Is it possible to place the above in any file(/etc/iptables.rules) so that I can use

> iptables-apply -t 60 /etc/iptables.rules

to avoid misconfiguration?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your /etc/iptables.rules file should look like this :

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

COMMIT
```

Comment: Then how about "iptables -F"?

Comment: iptables-apply flushes the rules prior to applying them anyway....

Comment: Ok!. Is it possible to log iptables other than logging in syslog?